# Adding <behavior name="myConfiguration"> throws UTF error -WCF

Tags: web-services, wcf, utf-8, web-config

I am trying to hook up one of my methods to be called after a get request is sent to the appropriate endpoint. When tampering with my web.config, I assigned a name to my behavior and i get the following error.

```
'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
```

Not sure why just assigning an attribute to my behavior throws this error.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Developer1.Core.Service.Developer1Service"
           bindingConfiguration="myConfiguration"     >
        <endpoint
            address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            contract="Developer1.Core.ServiceContracts.IDeveloper1Service" />
        <endpoint
            address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
            contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myConfiguration">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
            multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Seems when i take away  and don't have the name attribute, the error goes away. Any thoughts?

SOLVED!!!

I solved the issue seems I had to do what i was doing within a service library instead of an application. So now I am handling REST with my wcf Library and the other methods are handled within my WCF Application. Seems app config and web config differ in a way. Then I went to solution properties and selected to start multiple projects at once. Now i can hit methods with get requests within the library and the application runs all the other methods that arent dealing with HTTP protocal. My solution has a WCF Library and WCF Application within it. The Application uses web.config and the library uses app.config. following this article http://weblogs.asp.net/kiyoshi/wcf-using-webhttpbinding-for-rest-services works with the App config. My WCF application then inherits from my service file within my Library and does not contain any extra service methods, it just runs the methods within my WCF Library. But the Library is set up to handle HTTP requests. Probably not the correct solution but it works for me.

Comment: There's nothing that point to you problem in the code/conf you have shown. Can you show us the Request/Client side details?

Comment: I hv a reason to doubt because you have `webHttpBinding` which is Rest based. And somehow your client is sending `Soap` message to the `Rest` Endpoint. The error message says it all.

Comment: But there are many articles which show how to make REST work with certain methods within the wcf service. Have i configured it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You defined **myConfiguration** as bindingConfiguration for the service. But you do not have binding configurations at all. You defined service behavior with this name. It has nothing to do with binding.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? this article http://weblogs.asp.net/kiyoshi/wcf-using-webhttpbinding-for-rest-services shows how to make REST work with a wcf application and i have followed the steps identical. Once i add a name attribute to the behavior. The error occurs. Thank you for the response.

Comment: I solved the issue seems I had to do what i was doing within a service library instead of an application. So now I am handling REST with my wcf Library and the other methods are handled within my WCF Application. Seems app config and web config differ in a way. Then I went to solution properties and selected to start multiple projects at once. Now i can hit methods with get requests within the library and the application runs all the other methods that arent dealing with HTTP protocal